# How to explode component in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I have this code in my joomla template

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

How can I php explode the contents of this jdoc?

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve, what you have tried with some code.

Comment: You really need to explain what it is you want to happen. Are you saying you want to make a string? You would not want to do that in the template, it's not really appropriate to do that actually inside the html, you would want to do that before rendering starts (look at the list of events in the Joomla docs).  But really the question is not clear.  Also you may want to discuss this on jooma.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Here includes the output of your exntension or other joomla part at the specified position in the joomla template.

```
 <jdoc:include type="component" />
```

It is not clear what you want to achive.

It just add the content of your code in template at following path

templates/[yourtemplate]/html/com_content/article/default.php
Find the more information [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements#Component)

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: what part of jdoc you really want to explode?

Comment: I just want to add the whole frontpage, or at least he first article to a php variable.